# How should an array be passed to a Javascript function from C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control

I use a WebBrowser object from WPF and I'm calling some Javascript code in the page loaded in the browser like this:

```
myWebBrowser.InvokeScript("myJsFunc", new object[] { foo.Text, bar.ToArray<string>()});
```

Now, the js function is supposed to iterate over the elements of the second parameter (an array of strings) and do stuff accordingly.  The only issue is that the parameter seems not to be passed as a js array.

For example,

```
alert(typeof theArray);
```

alerts "Unknown".

What is the proper way to pass an array as a parameter when invoking a js function from CSharp?

Comment: Keep in mind that that `typeof [] == 'object'`.

Comment: I'm having a hard time taking anything useful out of such an object. `typeof problemArray` is `unknown`, and it's impossible to iterate over its fields.

Comment: try concat all items into a string seperating by ; or | for instance, and then in javascript, split it back to array

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe pass it as a json string instead and parse it in the js function

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(bar.ToArray<string>());

myWebBrowser.InvokeScript("myJsFunc", new object[] { foo.Text, json });
```

js:

```
function myJsFunc(json) {
   var data = JSON.parse(json);
   // do something with it.
}
```

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/03/12/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-using-javascriptserializer.aspx

Answer (score 5):

It's not solving the issue itself but it solves the problem if you have only one array to pass: you can send an arbitrary number of parameters to a JavaScript function, and access them through the `arguments` special variable. It becomes analogous to a function accepting a variable number of arguments, with the same advantages and problems (for instance, you *have* to pass the array last, and as mentioned earlier you can only pass one).

Here's an example JavaScript function:

```
function foo()
{
    var stringArgs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        stringArgs.push(arguments[i]);

    // do stuff with stringArgs
}
```

And you'd call it from C# like this:

```
List<string> arguments = new List<string>();
arguments.Add("foo");
arguments.Add("bar");
webBrowser.InvokeScript("foo", arguments.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you really want to squeeze every bit of performance out of the code you can avoid the deserialization by means of eval inside javascript. The concept is to structure the call like this:

```
((IHTMLWindow2)webBrowserControl.Document.Window.DomWindow).execScript("var returnValue = someFunction([ 'abc', 'xyz', '1', '2', '3' ], { foo: 'xyz', bar: 1 });"
```

Notice that we use .execScript which makes all the difference in the world. This is because contrary to .InvokeScript which would forcefeed the javascript method with **string** based arguments (which is what forces you to use eval on the javascript side), .execScript() gives us the ability to write arbitrary javascript code including what you see above (notice that the arguments are an explicit javascript array and a bag of properties). Now we can directly code arrays and objects and write them as arguments. In order to do that we just use Newtonsoft.Json to serialize arrays and objects:

```
class Test {
     public string foo;
     public int bar;
}
((IHTMLWindow2)webBrowserControl.Document.Window.DomWindow).execScript("var returnValue = someFunction(" +
JsonConvert.SerializeObject((new List<object>(2) { "abc", "xyz", 1, 2, 3 }).ToArray()) + ", " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Test() { foo = "xyz", bar = 1 }) + ");");
```

Another thing is retrieving the resulting returned value:

```
string result = (string)webBrowserControl.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { @"returnValue;" }));
```

For your convenience you might want to write a utility method which iterates over the given parameters and serializes them properly, invokes the function and then retrieves the returned value.

Comment: execScript was a nice option until IE11. Starting from IE11 it is not supported, so [msdn suggests using **eval** as a replacement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @anikiforov you are absolutely right. execScript was marked as deprecated for a long time. Then in IE11 in some update suddenly killed it without any prior warning on MS's behalf. Then many devs complained about the loss of functionality over COM. Then MS issued another update which allowed the use of .execScript over COM again (but the method is not available in javascript anymore - you can verify it using the dev tools in a fully updated IE11+). What a mess.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the array to a JS array first, something that looks like this:

```
["John", "Bob", "Sue"] // literal array
```

Two examples follow:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string[] stringArray = bar.ToArray<string>();

//Build the JS array.
sb.Append( "[");
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
{
    sb.AppendFormat( "'{0}', ", stringArray[i] );

}
sb.Append( "]");


// Now send the array to the JS function.
myWebBrowser.InvokeScript("myJsFunc", new object[] { foo.Text, sb.ToString() });
```

You may want to remove the trailing , as well. Don't forget to import the appropriate libraries for StringBuilder, which I think is System.Text.StringBuilder;

or use, example two:

```
string[] stringArray = bar.ToArray<string>();

// or simpler to use string join.
string jsArray = "[" + String.Join( ",", stringArray ) + "]";
//
myWebBrowser.InvokeScript("myJsFunc", new object[] { foo.Text, jsArray });
```

Comment: Passing this string structure, you automagically get an array on the JavaScript side, or you need to `eval` it?

Comment: It should auto be seen as a string is JavaScript, so you just process it as such in the JavaScript function. See here [JS Arrays](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/arrays.shtml)

Comment: If it's gonna show up as a string, people might as well use the JavaScriptSerializer class to support every kind of object then.