# pass multiple lists to javascript using invokescript using c#

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control

I use a webbrowser control to call a javascript function in a html file using InvokeScript(). I would like to pass four lists as parameters so I can use the data in the javascript function.

pseudocode:

```
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
        list1.Add("foo");
        list1.Add("bar");

        List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
        list2.Add("foo");
        list2.Add("bar");

        List<string> list3 = new List<string>();
        list3.Add("foo");
        list3.Add("bar");

        List<string> list4 = new List<string>();
        list4.Add("foo");
        list4.Add("bar");

        maps_webbrowser.Document.InvokeScript("initialize", list1.ToArray(), list2.ToArray() ,list3.ToArray() ,list4.ToArray());
```

I have read a post where a list is passed using a argument variable

[How should an array be passed to a Javascript function from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619931/how-should-an-array-be-passed-to-a-javascript-function-from-c)

Here's an example JavaScript function:

```
function foo()
{
var stringArgs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
    stringArgs.push(arguments[i]);

// do stuff with stringArgs
}
```

And you'd call it from C# like this:

```
List<string> arguments = new List<string>();
arguments.Add("foo");
arguments.Add("bar");
webBrowser.InvokeScript("foo", arguments.ToArray());
```

However, in this way only one list is passed.

The pseudocode I've wrote down does not work....

Comment: And your question? What didn't work? How have you declared your js function *initialize* ?

Comment: Sorry L. for the unclear post. I was working on the problem all night. After a good night of sleep I got some new ideas :)

Comment: @L.B I did some research and managed to awnser my question. Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After a good night of sleep I've basically got it working :)

According to the msdn an object array has to be passed as parameter:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452443(v=vs.110).aspx

C# code:

```
List<string> lat_waypoints = new List<string>();
lat_waypoints.Add("1.11111");
lat_waypoints.Add("2.12112");

List<string> lon_waypoints = new List<string>();
lon_waypoints.Add("34.1234");
lon_waypoints.Add("34.2345");

string lat_string = string.Join(",", lat_waypoints.ToArray());
string lon_string = string.Join(",", lon_waypoints.ToArray());

Object[] objArray = new Object[2];
objArray[0] = (Object)lat_string;
objArray[1] = (Object)lon_string;

maps_webbrowser.Document.InvokeScript("test", objArray);
```

Javascript:

```
<HTML>
<SCRIPT>
    function test(lat, lon) {

    var lat_split = lat.split(",");
    var lon_split = lon.split(",");

        alert("Lat: " +lat_split[0] + " lon: " + lon_split[0]);
    }
</SCRIPT>

<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This solution works but it is not the nicest solution in my opinion......

The lat and lon values are originally stored in an list with doubles. However, I don't know how to pass an array of doubles directly without converting it to string first.

Anyone else with some ideas?

Comment: @L.B What do you think of this?